# Using System.ComponentModel.Description in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This im my old code before ASP.NET 5 (vNext) change.

```
public enum HashType : short {
  [System.ComponentModel.Description( "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider" )]
  SHA1 = 0,
  [System.ComponentModel.Description( "SHA256Managed" )]
  SHA256 = 1,
  [System.ComponentModel.Description( "SHA384Managed" )]
  SHA384 = 2,
  [System.ComponentModel.Description( "SHA512Managed" )]
  SHA512 = 3,
  [System.ComponentModel.Description( "MD5CryptoServiceProvider" )]
  MD5 = 4
}
```

Now it gave me this error:

> The type or namespace name 'Description' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   UtilityPackage..NET Platform 5.4

And if I move mouse on it

[image]

this just not ends here, other part of code gives exception too. Like this one:

[image]

or this one

[image]

Also I should mention this code works perfectly in my Old classlibrary.

Answer (score 0):

DescriptionAttribute is no longer available. Use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.DisplayAttribute`.